# Outputting data and adding characters

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix

```
a=[1 2; 3 4; 5 6];
```

in MatLAB and I would like to export it to an external ASCII-file in the format `{1,2},{3,4},{5,6}`. How can I do that? Do I need to use low-level I/O?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `fprintf` as follows:

```
a=[1 2; 3 4; 5 6];

file_id=fopen('output.txt','w');
[m,n]=size(a);
for i=1:m-1
    fprintf(file_id,'{%d,%d},',a(i,1),a(i,2));
end
fprintf(file_id,'{%d,%d}',a(m,1),a(m,2));
fclose(file_id)
```